# Spring MVC: controller method params w/o @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Recently I've faced a strange behavior in Spring MVC (v4.3.7.RELEASE), especially from the `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`. What I tried to do is getting a link to my controller using `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`, so here are 2 examples:

#### What's clear

Having a controller like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/get")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView get(@RequestParam(required = false) String param1,
                            @RequestParam(required = false) String param2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then using `MvcUriComponentsBuilder` as `fromMethodCall(on(TestController.class).get(null, null)).toUriString()` results in expected link to */test/get*.

#### What's not clear

Same controller, but w/o `@RequestParam` annotations; same usage of `MvcUriComponentsBuilder`. But the result is */test/get?param1&param2*, i.e. it behaves as if they were annotated with `@RequestParam(required = true)`...

So before creating a bug for Spring just wanted to clarify if I'm not mistaken anywhere: should the absence of `@RequestParam` really behave the same as `@RequestParam(required = false)`? I was not able to find it in documentation, but it's in the code actually (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.7.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java#L79)